# Undefined Error in image source tag in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have crated object of objects as state props and I am using inside a function component in reatc js to display each image in row.But when i run my application I am getting undefined.jpg error

```
{Object.keys(props.stateData.images).map(image=>
<img id={image.imageType} src={require(`../../../public/images/${image.imageType}.jpg`)} 
alt = {image.imageType} style={{opacity:image.opacity}}/>)}
```

My stateData:

```
this.state = {images:
            {
                image1:{
                imageType:"image1",
                opacity:1
                },
                image2 :{
                    imageType:"image2",
                    opacity:1
                },
                image3:{
                    imageType:"image3",
                    opacity:1
                },
                image4: {
                    imageType:"image4",
                    opacity:1
                },
                image5:{
                    imageType:"image5",
                    opacity:1
                },
                image6:{
                imageType:"image6",
                opacity:1
                }
        }
        };
```

Comment: This will most probably be because the value in `${image.imageType}` goes undefined. Please post more code on how u get the values for `props.stateData.images`

Comment: @RohithMurali added my state data

Comment: How does this value get assigned to `props.stateData.images`.

Comment: stateData is this.state

Answer (score 0):

If the values are in state you can try accessing the value directly from state itself,

```
{Object.keys(this.state.images).map(image=>
<img id={image.imageType} src={require(`../../../public/images/${image.imageType}.jpg`)} 
alt = {image.imageType} style={{opacity:image.opacity}}/>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this approach - it's quick 'n dirty example.
https://codesandbox.io/s/y0wwz81909?fontsize=14

So the idea here is that you map over you 'images' object to get the key names - and in turn use that to fetch the correct object in state.